# How to enable angular sessionStorage

Tags: angularjs, sessionstorage

I am new to angular.js. I am trying to supposrt sessionStorage for a specific counter in my app using [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage/blob/master/ngStorage.js)

The following method returns the specific counter of comments. I want to store and read this counter using sessionStorage.

```
var commentCounter = function () {
    var commentCounter = {
        incrementCount:function () {
            var currentCount = myCounter.readPageViewCount();
            currentCount++;
            myCounter.recordPageViewCount(currentCount);
        },
        recordPageViewCount:function (pageViewCount) {
            var lastRecorded = new Date().toUTCString();

             // Need to record the counter
        },
        readPageViewCount:function () {
            var sessionCounter = 0;
            // Read counter from session
            return sessionCounter;
        }
    }
    return commentCounter;
}
```

Can anyone help me to handle this sessionStorage in right direction?

Comment: I think it is very clear in their documentation what to do: https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage, try to explain what have you tried so far and what result you get.

Comment: They even have live examples about how to use it: http://plnkr.co/edit/3vfRkvG7R9DgQxtWbGHz?p=preview